# instagram api search hashtags isn't reliable - so can I do this?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I'm looking to somehow tell users to upload a picture and do something, either tag or @ our company so we are notified in real time, i just need to fetch the url of the photo that was uploaded and tagged or @ or ANYTHING.

1. the hashtag search doesn't seem to work correctly, i've tried multiple hashtags and they wont retrieve them in any type of real time or at all.
2. the real-time subscription only notifies me that there is a new photo tagged that i subscribed to, so i have api search for a list of new media with that tag, which goes back to point 1, its not accurate or reliable.

so do i have any options at all on instagram?

If not do I have any options on facebook? any real time keyword search to grab the url of the photo they uploaded with a unique tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/chapmanu/hummingbird, it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with the Instagram Real-Time API is, that it is rather reliable.

When you get a real-time ping and then call the endpoint for your hashtag, the results are ordered newest first. 
You can then paginate until you hit the last known result.

Maybe this tutorial helps: http://www.mtrinitaria.com/mykhel/tutorial-instagram-real-time-photo-update-api-with-php/